# Reichsmark value

Tags: germany, currency

I've recently been left a lot of currency from my grandfather who fought in WWII.

Among a lot of Greek and Russian notes, I have received a Reichsmark for the value of 100,000.

Would anyone be able to tell me what it is worth in GBP? I'm not interested in selling it, as I am fascinated with currency from different periods and different countries, but I would just like to know.

Comment: [Google](http://www.history.ucsb.edu/faculty/marcuse/projects/currency.htm) The value is only to a collector; your best approach is to check ebay or your local numismatist.

Comment: For example, see http://www.ebay.com/bhp/reichsbanknote-1923; collector value depends upon condition and rarity.

Comment: Until the inflation ended in 1923, the currency was called Mark. Then came the Rentenmark and a year later the Reichsmark.

Comment: The 1st and 2nd series of the Rentenmark banknotes are very rare as is the 1st series of the Reichsmark. The following series of both are very common.

Answer (score 2):

The Reichsmark is no longer currency. One could make a hypothetical case what it would have been worth if the bearer had gone to an exchange office, which depends on whether it is a [pre-1923](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic) or [pre-1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Mark#Currency_reform_of_June_1948). In 1923, the rate was 1:1,000,000,000,000. In 1948, it was approx. 1:150.

So the hypothetical value could be 0.0000001 or 650 Marks.

Here is a [50 trillion Mark bill](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:50_Billionen_Mark_Stolberg_Eschweiler_001.jpg) (note that the non-US use of long-scale [billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion)).

As Peter Diehr pointed out, the collector's value today is unrelated to the nominal value.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan them for numismatically rare pieces, but depending on quantity most probably they worth a few hundred pounds, if any chance there is one or two rare note (limited availability) then more. As O.M. pointed out, the notes went through severe inflation, addition to this information, the notes were printed like there will be no tomorrow. That 100.000 Marks could be a single note or a nice stash of notes.

Rare notes might be found by printing year or some characteristics (misprints). It requires a lot of research or some help from a local coin dealer.

Comment: You can pick up Andrew Carnegie's gold backed bonds which yield 6% for next to nothing these days. Confederate US dollars sell well though...like Germany after World War 1 the US South had a hyperinflation during the US Civil War.